# Problem with SharpPCap

Tags: c#, .net, networking, sniffing

I get BSOD *almost* every time I abort the thread or close the device. Somebody with the same issues?

EDIT: I saw that it happens on the N-th time I close my app, even if I don't close the devices.

Comment: Closing the device should work, but `Thread.Abort` should never be used.

Comment: I just figured that out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bug in WinPcap driver.

The recently released version of WinPcap (4.1.2) fixes a bug that can cause a BSOD.

See [WinPcap 4.1.2 Change Log](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/changelog.htm#changelog_4_1_2).

Comment: Is there a silent installer of winpcap 4.1.2 ?

Comment: @blez, you can use WinPcap Professional. "As a Windows DLL, WinPcap Professional seamlessly and transparently integrates WinPcap functionality with your application. Consequently, your users are not aware of the installation of a third-party package with your application." http://www.cacetech.com/products/winpcap_pro.html

Answer (score 0):

If you get a BSOD, then this must be driver related, the WinPCAP or SharpPCAP version you use can barely be resposible (directly) of this. Check for updates or fixes for your NIC.

To check which driver is responsible have a look at the minidump (in `C:\%WINDIR%\Minidump) file with WinDbg. If you didn't write device drivers yet handling WinDbg might be a bit tedious. That would show you the culprit place, what I suppose is in the network card driver or related to it.

Comment: WinPCAP does work by loading a driver which layers over the NIC driver. So, it could be either the driver for the NIC or WinPCAP's driver.